# Catch all the text in one css declaration

Tags: html, css, drupal

I'm trying to catch all the elements of my website in one css declaration. It's a Drupal websites with a billion p's, a's, li's, ul's, strong's, all kinds of div's,...

So, pretty easy I thought and I added this in my css:

```
 body.i18n-zh-hans {
    color: red;
 }
```

But for some freakishly reason, the site doesn't move a muscle.

What's the proper declaration to catch ALL the text in just 1 CSS declaration?

Worst case scenario, I would have to declare everything on its own no? Like:

```
 body.i18n-zh-hans, #main p strong a li ul {
       color: red; 
 }
```

**UPDATE**

So, Basically, I just want to override all, in this example, the colors of the font in the whole website!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `body` even have that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the one and only solution!

```
.i18n-zh-hans * {
        font-size: 99% !important;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who participated this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to make that declaration `!important`, so it'd override any more "specific" styles specified elsewhere in your CSS. Remember that CSS has precedence rules, and "more specific" matches will have higher priority than "less specific" ones.

```
body.i18n-zh-hans {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Ok, great start, but doesn't work all the way. For example my `#main p` is still not red. Neither is `span#NewsTeaserTitle` or my links...

Comment: could be other !important declarations elsewhere too. Those are subject to the same precendence rules. Given two or more !important declarations, the one which is a better match will win.

Comment: There are indeed some more !important declarations in the CSS... But when it's stated `width: auto !important;`, it only applies on the width right? Not on everything else declared in that particular css declaration?

Comment: Yeah, it applies to that declaration only. It's a per-line thing, not a per-block.

Comment: OK, but the !important trick didn't work out. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
your style..
}
```

and you got to be the last rule in the list..
and there might be some inline styles, those will override..
tested it a bit out and figured out that everything you define in it needs !important..

Comment: Makes sense, but it's still not working with my `#main p` or `span#NewsTeaserTitle` for example

Comment: Ok, yours was closest to the final solution! Thanks!

Comment: Declarations are also prioritized when they have more specifity.  So you could also try * * { color: red !important; } and maybe even three asterisks and four asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
If body is the biggest box in the box model.  Get it?  You want to target the big container.  Try [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  It's a great tool. You can even edit the css on the browser to instantly change the website (not permanent though).

```
body {
     color: red !important;

     }
```

Comment: Yeah, figured that one out, but problem is I've to declare `body.i18n-zh-hans` and `body.i18n-zh-hans { color: red !important; }` doesn't work...